# Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb module 'sys' has no attribute 'audit'

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I encountered this error in Jupyter "Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb module 'sys' has no attribute 'audit'" when saving. I use Python 3.6 for interpretation, but I think for some reason Jupyter is using Python 3.9 installed in a different directory. Since the audit argument of the sys module only appeared in version 3.8

Comment: Can you post your code and traceback

Comment: The point is that this error occurs in the Jupyter shell, not when executing the program 

At the moment I'm using %notebook to save

Comment: Yeah but how can I reproduce this issue without code or without a file? Can you provide instructions on how to reproduce your error?

Comment: It turns out that I have the shutil module installed for python 3.9, starting from python 3.8 the auditing function was added, it is not supported by python 3.6 installed in anaconda